# How to raise an error when hidden BOM Character is detected in RUBY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, utf-8, byte-order-mark

Here is in Detail. I have a file which contains hidden BOM Characters as Shown Below

2225612|22225200240|STACKOVERFLOW|HELPSDEVELOPERS - LINE 1
**þÿ**2225612|22225200240|KIRK|CAPTAIN - LINE 2
2225612|22225200240|THANKS**þÿ**|INADVANCE - LINE 3

Now I have script where each row gets processed. As Per my assumption first line has to be processed since it doesn't have any BOM Character. But when second line starts processing it should raise an error since BOM Character is identified. Not only at the beginning of line the BOM Character can be anywhere in the row.For your reference the highlighted one is the BOM Character.

When I use regex **/[^[:print]]/** using **gsub** it is considering space or new line as an BOM Character. I want only BOM characters to be detected.

Can anyone writer script for this ?  Thanks in advance guys

Answer (score 2):

I think this regex should work:

```
if line =~ /\xEF\xBB\xBF/   # If line contains BOM character
   fail "Line contains a BOM char!"
end
```

If you have encoding issues, it might help to force both the line and regex to UTF-8, something like this:

```
regexp = Regexp.new("\xEF\xBB\xBF".force_encoding("UTF-8"), Regexp::FIXEDENCODING)
if line.force_encoding("UTF-8") =~ regexp
  # ...
```

Comment: Hi Ginty, Thanks for the reply

Comment: Can you look at the code in breif here

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559055/ruby-bom-characters-detection-needed

Comment: Hi @SivaAnil, if this solved the first part of your problem you should accept the answer

Comment: Please Have a look at my code here

https://codepen.io/sivaanil/post/my-test-code

Answer (score 0):

You can specify encoding with the File.read method.

```
File.read('your_file.txt', encoding: 'bom|utf-8')
```

or

```
File.readlines('your_file.txt', "r:utf-8")
```